# Update table order opencart

Tags: php, request, sql-update, opencart

Please tell me what could be the problem, can not get the variable order_id when the query is refreshed, if not specified, then all the request passes, but updates all records in the table, give advice where to look or what to read. 
Thank you!

**controller:**

```
public function edit(){

        if (isset($this->request->get['order_id'])) {
            $order_id = $this->request->get['order_id'];
        } else {
            $order_id = 0;
        }   

        if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $this->model_account_order->update($order_id, $this->request->post);
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/myorders', '', 'SSL'));
        }
```

....

```
        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/myorders/edite', '', 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->get['order_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
            $edit_order = $this->model_account_order->getOrderData($this->request->get['order_id']);
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['linkto'])) {
            $this->data['linkto'] = $this->request->post['linkto'];
        } elseif (isset($edit_order)) {
            $this->data['linkto'] = $edit_order['linkto'];
        } else {
            $this->data['linkto'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['description'])) {
            $this->data['description'] = $this->request->post['description'];
        } elseif (isset($edit_order)) {
            $this->data['description'] = $edit_order['description'];
        } else {
            $this->data['description'] = '';
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public function update($order_id,$data){
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "order SET forma = '" . $this->db->escape($data['forma']) . "', linkto = '" . $this->db->escape($data['linkto']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($data['description']) . "', cvet = '" . $this->db->escape($data['cvet']) . "', sizes = '" . (int)$data['sizes'] . "', counts = '" . (int)$data['counts'] . "', tcena = '" .(int)$data['tcena'] . "', sposob = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sposob']) . "' , delivery_usa = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_usa']) . "', hint = '" . $this->db->escape($data['hint']) . "', novapochta ='" . $this->db->escape($data['novapochta']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just very simple yet powerful solution - `$order_id` checking in the model:

```
public function update($order_id, $data) {
    if (!$order_id) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "order SET forma = '" . $this->db->escape($data['forma']) . "', linkto = '" . $this->db->escape($data['linkto']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($data['description']) . "', cvet = '" . $this->db->escape($data['cvet']) . "', sizes = '" . (int)$data['sizes'] . "', counts = '" . (int)$data['counts'] . "', tcena = '" .(int)$data['tcena'] . "', sposob = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sposob']) . "' , delivery_usa = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_usa']) . "', hint = '" . $this->db->escape($data['hint']) . "', novapochta ='" . $this->db->escape($data['novapochta']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
did everything written, but the problem persists, I think the error in:
if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $this->model_account_order->update($this->request->get['order_id'], $this->request->post);
   $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/myorders', '', 'SSL'));
  }
error:
Notice: Undefined index: order_id in

Comment: Then it seems like the URL the form is posted to does not contain `order_id`. How does the URL you are posting the form to look like?

Comment: fix it, had to sign `&order_id='.$order_id.'',`:
`$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/myorders/edite&order_id='.$order_id.'','', 'SSL');`